# How to read Firestore Geopoint coordinates in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After I have retrieved the firestore document in cloud functions, I need to be able to extract the lat and long of the field that I already know is a location. How do I do this?

This doesn't work:

```
if (element === "location" && documentAfter[element] !== undefined){
            console.log("location", documentAfter[element], documentAfter[element].latitude)
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the GeoPoint object call `_latitude` and `_longitude` like this:

```
documentAfter[element]._latitude
documentAfter[element]._longitude
```

Comment: Hmm, I can still do documentAfter[element].latitude and same for long (without underscore prefix) but the issue i'm having actually interpreting it as a geopoint object. Right now my solution is creating a new Geopoint(0,0), then setting that equal to documentAfter[element], and then reading lat and long from that object.

Comment: Let's say you have a document retrieved via snapshot. And in that document root there is GeoPoint property. To retrieve it you call var data =  doc.data(); and then var geopointObj = data.<Geopoint property name>. geoPointObj will be of type GeoPoint.